# Simple OpenCV project - detecting and tracking a tennis ball

Tags: opencv, object-detection, video-tracking

I have a project where I need to use OpenCV to detect an object (Tennis Ball) on a webcam, and for bonus credit, track it when I roll it across the table.

I haven't had much luck finding info on this, since I'm using OpenCV 2.4, C++, and a lot of information is in the older OpenCV version. I've read a lot of about different ways to do it, but I just don't know how to implement it into my code.

Any help would be appreciated, especially on how to integrate a detection/tracking function into my code

Here is my code so far, I think the image detection/tracking code should go after I apply the filters:

```
//Includes & Namespaces
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


//Main Function
int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture vid(0); //Capture from Webcam
    if(!vid.isOpened()) //Error Check for Webcam
    {
        cout << "Could not open camera" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat pic; //Create Matrix to store image
    namedWindow("video",1); //Open Window

    for(;;) //Infinite loop
    {
        Mat frame; //Create Matrix for a single frame
        vid >> frame; //Transfer from webcam to matrix

        //Filters
        cvtColor(frame, pic, CV_BGR2HSV);
        GaussianBlur(pic, pic, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);

        /*Image Detection Here */           

        imshow("Picture", pic); //Show image

        if(waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please use the [homework] tag.

Comment: Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFYWzrrUrL4 ?

Answer (score 9):

Did you try to google your question? There are many info about that.

Simple idea is next: detect your object using [color thresholding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884972/color-detection-opencv) (it seems that it's yellow or white color) and [circle detection](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html). After ball is deteccted you need to just track it using (for example) [Lucas-Kanade method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method).

Here are some guides/manuals:

1. [Tracking colored objects OpenCV](http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-opencv/)
2. [Motion Analysis and Object Tracking](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)
3. [Learning OpenCV](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do)
4. Look at OpenCV's folder `samples`. There'are many very useful examples. In your situation the best example is `samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp`.