# Android camera objects recognization

Tags: android, opencv, camera

Do somebody tried to recognize objects via Android camera? I want to write an application,which can recognize a products in a market. It can be by existing image for comparing or text detection.

I've tried to start with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/), but there not a lot of useful examples.
Found [SentiSight Embedded SDK](http://neurotechnology.com/sentisight-embedded.html).. The same problem, cannot find how it is works.

Could someone recommend a good solution?
Thanks for everyone.

Comment: you may read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085579/simple-opencv-project-detecting-and-tracking-a-tennis-ball

Comment: Not a variant. There all variants for C++. I didn't touch this language 8 years already :) Better for Java, if you know